# Nagios core High availability setup

Tags: nagios

Is there any solution available for master and slave steup in nagios, if master fails nagios must survey. Please suggest your ideas or links. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Nagios Core doesn't natively support HA (XI does so). You need to constantly check your master/slave and synchronize (e.g. rsync, puppet, ...) your retention.dat between them if one host fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have a master and slave  setup ,we use a script which will run from crontab  and basically do the below tasks

1) do a custome plugin check 
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -t 30 -H  $MASTER -c check_nagios &>/dev/null

2) copy the data via rsync

rsync -ae ssh $MASTER:/var/log/nagios/status.* /var/log/nagios/

3) enable notifications and event handlers on slave server.